# I want to know when to able to grammatically omit "that" leading an appositive clause

Tags: appositives

> She had a feeling (that) this would be the last time

Back in my school, I learnt not to omit "that' when it's leading an appositive clause as in the example, but I've just heard that with or without "that" , the sentence sounds natural.

So, I want to know when to able to grammatically omit "that" or not in this case.

Comment: I think you have a different understanding of *appositive* from the one I've picked up. It might be worth explaining what you understand by that term in your question.

Comment: @Minty I understand "appositive" as referring to its antecedent. So, in this case, "that ~ last time" is referring to "a feeling".

Comment: But doesn't a relative clause refer to its antecedent? In your previous post you were contrasting appositive and relative clauses, I thought.

Comment: @Minty Yeah right, I was. But I'm thinking my assumption on the previous question is definitely wrong now.

Comment: It is neither an appositive nor a relative clause. It's a declarative content clause functioning as complement of the noun "feeling", in which case the subordinator "that" is optional.

Comment: OK but there is a difference between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses - I'm not sure whether you mean appositive to refer specifically to one type. That can only appear in a restrictive relative clause and can be dropped when the relative clause relates to the object of the verb, but not otherwise - hopefully that answers your last question. That also has other functions, such as introducing a clausal complement of the verb. As user178049 has pointed out, that's the function it has in the sentence above

Comment: "(That) this would be the last time" is not a relative clause, but a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "feeling". It's better to restrict appositives to noun phrases, not complement clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user178049 says in a comment, "that this would be the last time" is functioning as the complement of "feeling" (just as it could function as the object of the verb "feel") and "that" is optional in this construction.

It is a different construction from

> She had a feeling [that] she recognised.

where the "that" clause *is* a modifier (adjunct, appositive if you will) to "feeling". "That" could also be omitted in this case, because the head of the relative clause ("feeling") is not its subject.

(My example is ambiguous until you get to the end, and find no object for "recognised", and realise it must be a relative clause. It's a "[garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)").

"She had a feeling that surprised her" is another with a relative clause, but here the "that" cannot be omitted in standard English, because the head of the relative clause (the feeling) is its subject.